# Finding the bounds of a region represented by data points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, boundary

For simplicity, I will consider the 2-D case but my question is well applicable to n-dimensions. I have a region S in 2-D that is closed and bounded and has no holes. The only thing I know about S is a bunch of data points that lie in S. Essentially, these points fill-up S; the more points I have, the more accurate my representation of S is. From these data points (x,y) in 2-D, I can easily approximate xL and xU such that all points (x,y) in S satisfy xL <= x <= xU.

I am wondering if there is a function or method in Matlab that enables me, for a particular point (x,y) in S, to give me the bounds of y approximated from these data points. In particular, I am looking for functions yL(x) and yU(x) such that yL(x) <= y <= yU(x) for any x such that xL <= x <= xU.

Now, I am not necessarily looking for a function in matlab like boundary which simply connects the points that are literally on the boundary of the data set. I am rather looking for the "best fit" boundary given the scattered plot that I have.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the [convex hull](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html)?

Comment: I may approximate S with a convex hull, however, S is not necessarily a convex hull and may have a non piecewise linear geometry